# TestNg failed due to NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I get this error when I try to run this as testng

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.setProperty(Unknown Source)
at com.w2a.base.TestBase.setUp(TestBase.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:326)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

some of the packages may be old, but I'm referring to an old tutorial, is it due to the old packages that i'm using.

- testng 6.11
- selenium-java 2.53.1
- extentreports 2.41.2
- reportng 1.1.4
- guice 4.1.0
- log4j 1.2.17
- mail 1.4.7
- mysql-connector-java  6.0.5
- poi 3.6
- poi-ooxml 3.6
- dom4j 1.1
- xmlbeans 2.3.0
- poi-ooxml-schemas 3.6

This is my TestBase class

```
    public class TestBase {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties config = new Properties();
    public static Properties OR = new Properties();
    public static FileInputStream fis;
    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        if(driver == null) {
             FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\acer\\eclipse-workspace\\DataDrivenFramework\\src\\test\\resources\\properties\\Config.properties");
             config.load(fis);     
             System.out.println(config.getProperty("browser"));

             fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\acer\\eclipse-workspace\\DataDrivenFramework\\src\\test\\resources\\properties\\OR.properties");
             OR.load(fis);

        }
                 if(config.getProperty("browser").equals("chrome")) {
                 System.out.println("You won");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\acer\\eclipse-workspace\\DataDrivenFramework\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe"));
                driver = new ChromeDriver();                

             }
                 System.out.println("You won");
             driver.get(config.getProperty("testsiteurl"));
             driver.manage().window().maximize();
             driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("implicit.wait")), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //}
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() {
        if(driver != null)
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Why this testng test case failed?

I'm using chromedriver.exe 2.28.

Comment: As rightly pointed out by user7294900. System.setProperty is needed for browsers apart from the native i.e. Firefox. In your code, there is one mistake.

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\acer\\eclipse-workspace\\DataDrivenFramework\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe"));

Remove the "System.setProperty" again inside the brackets and give the path direct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must enter value in `System.setProperty`:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\acer\\eclipse-workspace\\DataDrivenFramework\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe");
```